# how to generate a random choice when i have a list of 2 dimensional?

Tags: python, numpy

If a list like this `:L = [(1, 2), (2, 2), (3, 0)]`
where i want to random choice an element of L, it returns an Error saying `the element of L must be 1-dimensional`. So, how should i use random.choice when the elements are not 1-dimensional?

```py
import numpy as np
L = [(1, 2), (2, 2), (3, 0)]
re = np.random.choice(L)
```

when i try code above, it reports wrong

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple solution to this is to take a random index of the list, instead of the element itself:

```
import numpy as np
L = [(1, 2), (2, 2), (3, 0)]
random_index = np.random.choice(len(L))
re = L[random_index]
```

Comment: If this solved your problem, please accept the answer.

Answer (score 0):

numpy is a matrix library so it confused L with a 2D array. Use builtin random module instead:

```
import random
L = [(1, 2), (2, 2), (3, 0)]
re = random.choice(L)
```